# maven colored logging breaks filepath

Tags: quickfix, makeprg

If I use the color logging for maven, the file path is corrupted by the coloring syntax:

```
^[[1;31m[ERROR]^[[m /home/foo/bar/src/main/java/com/domain/bar/App.java
```

instead of

```
[ERROR] /home/foo/bar/src/main/java/com/domain/bar/App.java:[48,50] cannot find symbol
```

How can I have a colored output and correct path for the quickfix window?

I use http://www.aheritier.net/united-colors-of-maven/ to have colored output.

Comment: I have the same issue using https://github.com/jcgay/maven-color

Comment: Can pipe the data through something like `col -b` to remove the color escape codes?

Comment: I would like to have the color during the build, color can be remove by `MAVEN_OPTS="$MAVEN_OPTS -Dmaven.color=false"`. When I build C I have no issue with the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to have color working into vim and console is to use
https://github.com/jcgay/maven-color

Then set the colored log pattern into `/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/logging/log4j2.xml`

```
<Console name="maven-color-true" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{[%p] %mavenMsg%n%rEx}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WAR>
</Console>
```

The tips is to keep the leading `[ERROR]` using `[%p]` into the pattern.

Then into `maven-compiler.vim/compiler/mvn.vim` (thanks @Peter Rincker)

```
CompilerSet errorformat+=%E%.%#[ERROR]\ %f:[%l\\,%c]\ %m,%Z
```

or the solution is to have color for console and into vim deactivate color in `maven-compiler.vim/compiler/mvn.vim`:

```
CompilerSet makeprg=MAVEN_OPTS=\"$MAVEN_OPTS\ -Dmaven.color=false\"\ mvn
```

Answer (score 2):

Vim does not support Ansi escape color codes. The [AnsiEsc.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) plugin attempts to fix this for some cases. However I doubt AnsiEsc can be combined with the quickfix list in any meaningful way.

I suggest you remove the color from your maven output so you can use the quickfix functionality like `:cnext`/`:cprev`. Here is a [simple `'errorformat'` value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069095/errorformat-for-maven3-in-vim) for maven 3:

```
set errorformat=[ERROR]\ %f:[%l\\,%v]\ %m
```

For more help see:

```
:h :make
:h 'makeprg'
:h 'errorformat'
:h errorformat
:h quickfix
```